# Chart.js not deploying properly on Heroku

Tags: javascript, angularjs, heroku, chart.js, angular-chart

I have been using angular-chart.js with my app locally and I have not had a problem. However, when I deploy my app on Heroku, I my page breaks because it Chart.js is not deployed properly.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < Chart.min.js:1

Uncaught ReferenceError: Chart is not defined angular-chart.min.js:1

Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.6/$injector/modulerr?p0=swellsApp&p1=Error%…swells.herokuapp.com%2Fassets%2Flibs%2Fangular%2Fangular.min.js%3A19%3A463) angular.min.js:38
```

I don't get these error when I run it on my local server. I'm sourcing the scripts properly and have included my dependencies in my app as well. What I don't understand is that my other scripts have been loading with no problem. It's just Chart.js that is giving me the issue...

Any thoughts???

**What I see under Resources in Chrome's DevTools**

[image]

**index.html**

```
 <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Swells</title>
    <!-- For Angular Routing -->
    <base href="/">
    <!-- CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="public/assets/libs/normalize-css/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootswatch/3.3.5/darkly/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.4.0/animate.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/libs/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../../assets/css/style.css">

    <!-- JAVASCRIPT LIBS -->
    <script src="assets/libs/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/Chart.js/Chart.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/libs/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>

    <!-- MAP API -->
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>

    <!-- Controllers -->
    <script src="app/controllers/mainCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/userCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/mapCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/surfCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/weatherCtrl.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers/surfReportCtrl.js"></script>

    <!-- Services -->
    <script src="app/services/authService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/userService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/surfService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/weatherService.js"></script>
    <script src="app/services/surfReportService.js"></script>


    <!-- Main Angular Files -->
    <script src="app/routes.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>

    <!-- SET VEIWPORT FOR MOBILE -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, intitial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module('swellsApp', [
  'appRoutes',
  'authService',
  'userService',
  'surfService',
  'weatherService',
  'surfReportService',
  'mainCtrl',
  'userCtrl',
  'surfCtrl',
  'mapCtrl',
  'surfReportCtrl',
  'weatherCtrl',
  'ngMessages',
  'ngAnimate',
  'ui.bootstrap',
  'chart.js'
])
  //application configuration to integrate tokens into our requests
  .config(function($httpProvider){
    //attach auth interceptor to the http requests
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('AuthInterceptor');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

I found an alternate solution to this problem. I sourced a CDN for Chart.js and that worked. It seems that Chart.js was deploying with my app for some reason so I decided to source it from a cdn and that did the trick

```
 <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/1.0.2/Chart.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ahve that error when I have a mistake on the src property of my libs.

check that this line is ok:

```
<script src="assets/libs/angular-chart.js/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>
```

Maybe you misspell the src path.

What about if you change to this `<script src="assets/libs/angular-chart/dist/angular-chart.min.js"></script>` I think that angular-chart.js is not the name of the folder

Comment: Yeah I actually had a different src path before this and it pointed to another angular-chart.js file. That doesn't seem to be the issue because it runs fine on my local server. Just not on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Check your angular.json file for Chart.min.js and change both instances to all lowercase.  Heroku is case sensitive.

Worked for me using Angular 13.